# Spresense SDK チュートリアルにおける「ボードへ書き込みます」が行えません

Tags: spresense

https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_tutorials_ja.html
↑SDKチュートリアル
これの2.1の項アラームサンプルアプリケーションの作成時
2.2.1ビルド手順の＜nuttx.spk を Spresense ボードへ書き込みます。＞が行えなくて困っています。
COMポートの確認方法はわかってCOM3につなげていることも分かっています。

Answer (score 0):

コマンドライン版を使用されている場合、

`make`を実行してビルドが終わった後に、

```
$ make
```

次のように`COM3`を指定すれば書き込みできると思います。

```
$ tools/flash.sh -c COM3 nuttx.spk
```